# How to enable basic caching with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, caching, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to enable basic caching with Spring Data JPA. But I cannot understand why the DAO methods are still querying the database instead of using the cache.

Given the following Spring Boot 1.5.1 application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class PasswordsController {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordService service;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping("/passwords.htm")
    public void passwords(Map model,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.put("passwords", service.getPasswords(request));
    }
...
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PasswordService extends BaseService {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordJpaDao passwordDao;

    public Collection<Password> getPasswords(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Collection<Password> passwords = passwordDao.getPasswords(params);
        return passwords;
    }
...
```

Interface

```
@Transactional
public interface PasswordJpaDaoCustom {

    public Collection<Password> getPasswords(PasswordSearchParameters params);
}
```

and implementation

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.crm.entity.Password;
import com.crm.search.PasswordSearchParameters;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class PasswordJpaDaoImpl implements PasswordJpaDaoCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Cacheable("passwords")
    public Collection<Password> getPasswords(PasswordSearchParameters params) {
       System.err.println("got here");
       return em.createQuery(hql, Password.class);  
    }
...
```

Maven Dependencies

```
<!-- Spring Boot start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring Boot end -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I understand that Spring Boot will implicitly use `ConcurrentHashMap` for caching without any specific configuration necessary?

But the `getPasswords()` dao method is always called instead of using the cache. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, spring boot by default uses `ConcurrentHashMap` for caching and the issue with your code is that **you did not set any `key` for your `passwords` cache**, so it is calling the database every time for fetching the data.

So you need to the key (any unique identifier) using the `params` object variables as shown below:

```
@Cacheable(value="passwords", key="#params.id")//any unique identifier
public Collection<Password> getPasswords(PasswordSearchParameters params) {
   System.err.println("got here");
   return em.createQuery(hql, Password.class);  
}
```

Comment: I cannot provide a unique key from "params", "params" is just an encapsulation of a search form input fields, all can be null. If all are null, all passwords are returned. Can I still cache the method call?

Comment: No, you will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation`

Comment: You can set some default keys, like may be "-1" or something else (application specific)

Comment: Thanks, I moved the `Cacheable` annotation to the service layer and used the session id instead `@Cacheable(value="passwords", key="#request.session.id")`.

Comment: It works, but... `request.session.id` unique to each session right, so you will end multiple cache data for each user login, is this expected?

Comment: So, you can set some default keys, like may be "-1" or something else (application specific) when user enters null vaues

Comment: How do I check if params values are null and provide a default if they are?

Comment: If they are coming as `@RequestParam`, you can set the `defaultValue`, you can look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html